# "Access denied" to C:\Documents and Settings after removing malware?

Tags: malware

My Windows 7 PC became infected with the so-called "Malware Protection designed to protect" trojan while I was at work the other day.

I managed to kill the process so that the malware is no longer running.

The removal instructions specify to delete the following file:
c:\documents and settings\all users\application data\defender.exe

However, when I click to c:\documents and settings, it says "Access denied".  Prior to this malware infection, I've never had any trouble accessing "Documents and Settings" or "Application Data."

I read that in Windows 7, c:\documents and settings is a psudonym for c:\users, but I still cannot find the file defender.exe.

Suggestions?

Comment: As Merlyn Morgan-Graham commented on my brain-fart, and now-deleted post, that is normal behavior. Do nothing to c:\documents and settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening `C:\Documents and Settings\` is expected to give you problems in Windows 7.  It does this on every Windows 7 box, fresh from install.  This is normal, and can be ignored.

The directory `C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\` is itself a [NTFS Junction Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) (what you called a "pseudonym"), so you can't open it either.

The directory you want is `C:\ProgramData\`.

Comment: @KCotreau: We all make mistakes, sorry to be assertive.  You'll admit it was bad advice ;)

Comment: I totally agree.